# Multiple Aggregate with different Group By

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have table User, Company, ParentCompany and table Goal.
Each Company have ParentCompany, and each User inside one Company. Goal have number of action, and type of Goal, user who execute the goal, and time executed.

I want to calculate the number of action in a date range for each type of Goal, for each user, company, and parent_company. Number of action for each company equal to sum of action for user that reside in that company.

More or less after some join query, I able to get this table below, where column id is id of company, parent_id is id of companyparent, and num is number of goal for all user inside of id company.

```
id          parent_id            num
----------- -------------------- -----------------------
1           3                    1
2           1                    2
3           1                    1
4           2                    4
```

Now I want to make it like below:

```
id          parent_id            sum_id         sum_parent
----------- -------------------- -------------- -------------
1           3                    1              1
2           1                    2              3
3           1                    1              3
4           2                    4              4
```

How can I make it works? I can get one of the value (sum_id or sum_parent) with GROUP BY,

```
SELECT id,SUM(num) AS sum_id FROM tableA GROUP BY id
```

or

```
SELECT parent_id,SUM(num) AS sum_parent FROM tableA GROUP BY parent_id
```

but is there any way to make it only in one query? `tableA` results from query with 5 join inside.

Comment: What is the query which you are using

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to make it like below"? Do you want to change your table structure or that is your expected output? And if it is your expected output what is logic behind `sum_id` and `sum_parent` columns?

Comment: First table is a result from 4 join query. The sum_id is sum from num with same id, sum_parent is sum from num with same parent_id.

Comment: Can you explain how sum_parent of id (1) become 4? or id (2) become 12 ?

Comment: Just post on your two query of getting sum_parent and sum_id separately, if you already have those two querys.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.parent_id, a.sum_id, b.sum_parent
FROM (SELECT id, parent_id, SUM(num) sum_id FROM tableA a GROUP BY id) a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT parent_id, SUM(num) sum_parent FROM tableA a GROUP BY parent_id) b ON a.parent_id = b.parent_id
```

Comment: tableA is a result from 5 join. Will it affect the performance because joining tableA with tableA?

Comment: @dieend Then add full query with table structure to understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT
    t1.id, t1.parent_id, t1.sum_id, t2.sum_parent
FROM
    (SELECT id, parent_id, SUM(num) AS  sum_id FROM mytable GROUP BY id) t1 
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT parent_id, SUM(num) AS sum_parent FROM mytable GROUP BY parent_id) t2 
    ON t1.parent_id = t2.parent_id
```

Comment: mytable is a result from query with 5 join. Is there any way so it isn't duplicate query?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently what I want can be done with `WITH ROLLUP` statement. (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

With

```
SELECT id,sum(num) FROM tableA GROUP BY parent_id, id WITH ROLLUP;
```

will results in

```
parent_id   id                  sum(num)
----------- -------------------- -------------- 
1           2                    2              
1           3                    1              
1           null                 3              
2           4                    4              
2           null                 4              
3           1                    2              
3           null                 2
```